# string to int inside linq2sql lambda expression

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a lambda expression that returns the sum of two fields in a table. The problem is that the field (ExpectedQuantity) is a string, while QtyExpected is an int. I thought I would be able to use int.Parse in my lambda expression, but I get an error saying that SQL cannot translate it.

```
return new QuantitiesDashboardAggregate()
        {
            QtyExpected = query.Sum(x => int.Parse(x.ExpectedQuantity)),
            QtyReceived = query.Sum(x => int.Parse(x.ReceivedQuantity)),
        };
```

Can someone help?

Here is how I defined the query variable:

```
 IQueryable<Data.POProduct> query = this.Database.POProducts;

        // Apply date range
        DateRange dateRange = new DateRange(args.DateRangeFilter, args.DateRangeCriteria);

        switch (dateRange.DateRangeFilter)
        {
            case DateRangeFilter.Date:
                query = query.Where(po => po.PurchaseOrder.FiscalDate.Date == dateRange.Date);
                break;
            case DateRangeFilter.FiscalWeek:
                query = query.Where(po => (po.PurchaseOrder.FiscalDate.Year == dateRange.Year) &&
                                          (po.PurchaseOrder.FiscalDate.WeekYear == dateRange.Number));
                break;
            case DateRangeFilter.FiscalPeriod:
                query = query.Where(po => (po.PurchaseOrder.FiscalDate.Year == dateRange.Year) &&
                                          (po.PurchaseOrder.FiscalDate.Period == dateRange.Number));
                break;
            case DateRangeFilter.FiscalYear:
                query = query.Where(po => po.PurchaseOrder.FiscalDate.Year == dateRange.Year);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Comment: How do you get your 'query' variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically Linq to SQL cannot translate your expression, so you should call `.ToList() (or .AsEnumerable())` on your query, it will fetch data drom db, and than you can use your expression with int.Parse

Comment: Do you mean: int.Parse(query.Sum(x => x.ExpectedQuantity).ToList())? This does not work, the Sum is still telling me it cannot convert.

Comment: No, it wouldn't help, can you provide a code where you initialize query variable ?

Comment: try to change IQueryable<Data.POProduct> query = this.Database.POProducts to var query = this.Database.POProducts.ToList()

Comment: If I do that, the subsequent lines in the switch statement won't compile because query gets converted to a List<PoProduct>.